# Obter dados da web para string VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Bom dia! desenvolvi algumas macros e funções para meu uso na empresa e gostaria de efetuar uma validação quanto a sua utilização buscando em uma pagina da web.
a pagina na verdade é um blogspot. na qual deixarei um post com um texto somente.

tipo. se tiver tal conteúdo na web execute a macro, caso contrario não execute.

seria como uma trava para usuários indesejados da macro.

o problema é que não encontro informação de como fazer essa verificação da web.
alguém teria alguma sugestão? material onde eu possa encontrar!

Comment: O local onde está esse texto precisará de alguma validação, como usuário, senha, cookies e/ou token, ou é uma requisição HTML simples?

Comment: @CésarRodriguez é uma requisição simples, coloquei um exemplo em [link](http://jsrconfig.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 2):

embuti em meu formulário o seguinte código

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  Dim validacao, retorno As Variant
  Dim site As Object
  Set site = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
  On Error GoTo proximo
  site.Open "GET", "https://jsrconfig.blogspot.com/"
  site.Send
  validacao = site.responsetext
  retorno = InStr(1, validacao, "habilitados", vbTextCompare)
  If retorno = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("As macros foram dasabilitadas pelo criador!!")
    For Each item In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
      ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove item
    Next item
   Unload MENU
 End If
proximo:
```

se houver uma forma mais simples aceito sugestões

Comment: É isso mesmo. Não respondi porque estou em viagem em lugar com acesso restrito à Internet.

Comment: @CésarRodriguez obrigado pelo retorno!